# How to autowire SessionFactory to a Repository class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can someone please help me to autowire `SessionFactory` to a `Repository` class in `Spring`? Following code gives me this error. Any suggestion to overcome this problem. I checked many similar topics in StackOverflow but none of them were successful.

> "Error creating bean with name 'appointmentController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'iFactory': Error creating bean
>   with name 'appointmentFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through field 'factory': No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency ...etc"

*Repository class*

```
@Repository
    @ComponentScan({"org.hibernate.SessionFactory"})
    public class AppointmentFactory {
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory factory ;

        public SessionFactory getFactory() {
            return factory;
        }

        public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
            this.factory = factory;
        }
    }
```

*Controller class*

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan({"com.mobios.ep.services","com.ombios.ep.entity.factory")
public class AppointmentController {
    @Autowired
    private AppointmentService iService;
    @Autowired  
    private AppointmentFactory iFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value="appointment/get", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public AppoinmentWM getApointmentById(@RequestBody AppointmentReq appointment) throws Exception{
        Log4JUtil.logger.info("APPOINTMENT,appointment_get_request,Request="+appointment.toString());
        AppointmentService appoinmentService = new AppointmentService();
        StatsService statsService = new StatsService();
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
        AppoinmentWM gotAppointment = null;

    }
```

Comment: how did you configure sessionFactory? maybe the entityManager is defined instead?

Comment: In this application, there are three projects. One project is spring project (epWeb) which contains controllers. One Java project has services (epService). And there is another java project(epEntity) has Repositories which uses hibernate to connect to the DB. Spring project has dependencies of both services and repository projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
            @Autowired
            DataSource dataSource;

            @Bean(name = { "sessionFactory" })
            public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

                LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory  = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
                sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
                sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mypackage.my.entities" });
                sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
                return sessionFactory;
            }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return txManager;
        }
          Properties hibernateProperties() {
            return new Properties() {
                {
                    // @formatter:off
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));


             }
          };
    }
```

Or

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    //@Autowired
    //HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;

    @Autowired
    HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean(name = { "sessionFactory" })
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
        // HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new
        // HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        // factory.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        // return factory.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: In epEntity project, It has repository classes for DB access. So, with that how can I use this code?

Answer (score 1):

I think in the constructor but I'm struggling with this too currently

```
public AppointmentFactory(@Qualifier("mySessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
 }
```